# Se puede crear un max lenght para span , div o p

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hola que tal esta es mi duda: se que existe un atributo para `input` y `text-area` con el cual se manipula la cantidad de caracteres como `maxlenght`, mi pregunta es si esto se puede hacer con `span`, `div` o cualquier otra etiqueta. Mi idea es tener algo así como:

```
<span maxlength="9">David Perez</span>
```

Pero que en pantalla SOLO se muestre:

```
David Per
```

Si la solución es por **JQuery**, **JavaScript** o **CSS** no importa agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera sencilla es cortar la cadena de caracteres, yo lo hago con javascript. Por ejemplo:

```
var substr;
var str = "cadena";

substr = str.substring(0, 3);
console.log(substr);
```

esto como resultado te imprimirá en pantalla `cad` que solo son 3 caracteres que tenemos asignados para cortar la cadena de caracteres y por ultimo para imprimir el dato en el *`span`* solo hay que darle un id. Por ejemplo:

*html*

```
<span id="nombre"> </span>
```

*javascript*

```
document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML = substr;
```

*todo el ejemplo:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<span id="nombre"> </span>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Imprimir cadena</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var substr;
    var str = "cadena";

    substr = str.substring(0, 3);

    document.getElementById("nombre").innerHTML = substr;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El atributo `maxlength` es solo para las etiquetas `input` y `textarea`. Puedes emular lo mismo con JavaScript en cualquier componente.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('cut');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let lines = document.querySelectorAll('.line');
  [].forEach.call(lines, line => applyMaxLen(line, 10));
});

function applyMaxLen (el, maxChars = 5) {
  el.textContent = el.textContent.substring(0, maxChars);
}
```

```css
.line {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 .25rem;
}
#cut {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="line">Hola, ¿cómo estás?</span>
<span class="line">Bien, gracias, ¿y tú?</span>
<button id="cut">Cortar</button>
```